# Why wont MySQL query use index?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have tried several different ways but I can not figure out why my query would not be using the index.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT 
    allocationdate,
    SUM(linepersonal) as recpts
FROM
    c1.recpt #force index (rbadateptype) #force index (rbADate)
WHERE
    allocationdate BETWEEN 20120101 AND 20140630 
        AND ptype = 3
GROUP BY YEAR(allocationdate);
```

Without forcing indexes:

```
+----+-------------+--------+------+----------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys        | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------+------+----------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | recptb | ALL  | rbADate,rbADatePtype | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 23186904 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------+------+----------------------+------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Forcing rbadateptype:

```
+----+-------------+--------+------+----------------------+----------------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys        | key            | key_len | ref  | rows     | extra                                        |
+----+-------------+--------+------+----------------------+----------------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | recptb | ALL  | rbADate,rbADatePtype | rbAdatePtype | 9       | NULL | 8199594| Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+--------+------+----------------------+----------------+---------+------+----------+----------------------------------------------+

`allocationDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
`pType` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
KEY `rbADate` (`allocationDate`),
KEY `rbAdatePtype` (`allocationDate`,`patType`),
```

One of the interesting things things that I cannot explain is how the index on just the date says that it needs to look through 7,784,810 records but a composite index on the date and ptype needs to look at 8,199,594.

**An even more interesting thing that I just noticed is that using the rbAdate index it says that it needs to look through 23,186,904 records when a select count(1) returns 21,610,791.**

Comment: MySQL thinks the index is not selective and a complete filescan would be faster then using the index - so it seems. Every third record will be used. You could try an composite index on (allocationdate, ptype).

Comment: One of the interesting things things that I cannot explain is how the index on just the date says that it needs to look through 7,784,810 records but a composite index on the date and ptype needs to look at 8,199,594.

Comment: The row count in an EXPLAIN is not 100% accurate. This question gives a few more details - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961745/explain-and-count-returning-two-different-values

Comment: @Kickstart Thank you, that helps explain why my counts are confusing.