# rows in mysql explain bigger than real rows

Tags: mysql, performance, explain

DB：Mysql 5.6, Innodb,[image: the index]

explain result:
[image: explain result]

the real data:
[image]

I'm confused where does the 16462900 come from. When I set 6 wave_no, the rows in explain result is 6:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the rows returns by "explain" is not equal to count()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037471/why-the-rows-returns-by-explain-is-not-equal-to-count)

Answer (score 1):

The value of `rows` in the EXPLAIN output is an estimate of the number of rows that will be examined.

It's just an estimate, based on the calculated statistics.

References:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain-output.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-persistent-stats.html

Comment: but the real row is 360408, is that possible that rows in explain much bigger than real row ?

Comment: @Cedric: Yes, it's possible that the value reported for `rows` in the EXPLAIN output will be larger (or smaller) than the number of rows in the table. It's not an *exact* count of rows. The optimizer *estimates* the number of rows to be examined. (There's several reasons the estimates are a lot different... the statistics aren't up to date, distribution of key values on the pages that InnoDB used for statistics, et al.) The question you asked was "Where does the [rows value in EXPLAIN output] come from?."  it comes from the optimizer, and is based on the table/index statistics.

Comment: What do you mean "index doesn't work"? The EXPLAIN output is showing that the execution plan will use the `IDX_COM_WAVE` index.

Answer (score 1):

Use this 'composite' index to improve performance:

```
INDEX(com_uid, exchange_state, wave_no)
```

And remove the `FORCE`.

The statistics are sometimes that far off.  This can especially happen if there are `TEXT` or `BLOB` columns, which are stored elsewhere, thereby messing with the arithmetic.  Don't worry about it.

You *could* do `ANALYZE TABLE` to recalculate the stats, but that might not improve the stats.

Answer (score 0):

My college said this because of **table fragmentation**, you can search it from Google, here is [one](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3927871/MySQL-Data-Fragmentation---What-When-and-How.htm#:%7E:text=MySQL%20tables%2C%20including%20MyISAM%20and,read%20when%20scanning%20the%20table.) .

> MySQL tables, including MyISAM and InnoDB, two of the most common types, experience fragmentation as data is inserted and deleted randomly. Fragmentation can leave large holes in your table, blocks which must be read when scanning the table. Optimizing your table can therefore make full table scans and range scans more efficient.

Here is the [article](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-file-defragmenting.html) in official site.